# NUMA - all CPU's bound to node 0

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, rhel6, numa

I am running Dell PE 815 servers with two 16-core Opteron's, with four memory modules on each, OS - RHEL6, when I've started optimizing it for NUMA operation, found, that all cores are shown as bound to node0:

```
[root@node1 ~]# numactl --show
policy: default
preferred node: current
physcpubind: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
cpubind: 0
nodebind: 0
membind: 0
[root@node1 ~]# numactl --hardware
available: 1 nodes (0)
node 0 cpus: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
node 0 size: 65462 MB
node 0 free: 5889 MB
node distances:
node   0
  0:  10
[root@node1 ~]# numastat
                           node0
numa_hit              2661443864
numa_miss                      0
numa_foreign                   0
interleave_hit             43010
local_node            2661443864
other_node                     0
[root@node1 ~]#
```

According to physical configuration, there must be at least two nodes.
What can be the reason?

Comment: Can be a enabled "node interleaving" virtually expose all the HW to the system this way?